# Empty line should have the same properties or making a <code> section

Tags: html, css

I trying to format a code section with CSS:

```css
    code {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
 color: #022140;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-left: 6px solid #ccc;
    white-space: pre;
    }
```

```html
<code>
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name domain.tld;
    root /var/www/html/docroot;
}
</code>
```

I have the following problems:

- An empty line in the `<code>` section is actually displayed as a real empty line in my browser - it does not get formated like the rest of the content in the `<code>` section.
- The newlines between `<code>` and `server {` and `}` and `<code>` are actually displayed as newlines in the browser - how could I avoid that without writing `<code>server {` and `}</code>` accordingly?

**EDIT**

The preview here in stackoverflow is not working correctly (does not show the problem), that's why I'm adding a screenshot to depict the real problem:

[image]

The problem appears both on Chrome 68.0.3440 and Firefox 61.0.2.

Comment: I added a snippet, make sure it shows your problem since space and lines are considered

Comment: It's not working correctly here - the same snippets create a blank white line between `listen 80 ...` and `server_name ...` in my environment.

Comment: I see that blank line too ... add a screenshot of what you see with the snippet and tell us the browser you are using

Comment: As desired I added a screenshot and Information about the browsers I'm using.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on any browser on either Windows or macOS. What do the browser dev tools tell you?

Comment: is it a wordpress by any chance? ... am pretty sure if you inspect the code you will see two `code` tags

Comment: Yes it is a wordpress and yes I have another `code` section from `_code.scss` I don't know where those CSS are coming from. When not using wordpress the problem really does not appear.

Comment: with wordpress NEVER EVER use the *visual* tab when adding codes, always stay on the *text* tab or use widget that adds html ... The native wrodpress editor handle badly html code

Comment: I disabled the visual editor, I'm using the text tab.

Comment: if you are also getting issue with the text tab consider plugins that allow you to add raw html

Comment: Thank you very much Termani